# How to get event.target.result in javascript indexdb typescript working?

Tags: javascript, typescript, indexeddb

In my javascript/typescript project I have this code

```
        request.onupgradeneeded = (event: IDBVersionChangeEvent) => {
            console.log('idb onupgradeneeded firing');
            const db = event.target.result;
            //if (db != null) {
                //console.log(`Upgrading to version ${db.version}`);
                if (!request.result.objectStoreNames.contains(this.#name)) {
                    request.result.createObjectStore(this.#name, {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement:true});
                }
            //}
        };
```

But the problem is this code

`event.target.result;`

Shows an underline saying `Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`

How can I fix this in typescript?

Comment: Can't you use `const db = request.result`?

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough type information in handler callback type provided by `dom` Typescript library.

Probably you can define your own typing for `indexedDB.open`, but it looks much simpler to just downcast target manually:

```js
const db = (event.target as IDBOpenDBRequest).result;
```

Or, as @kelsny suggested, use the original request object:

```js
const db = request.result; // event.target === request
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a src/type-patches/indexeddb.d.ts file with this kind of content:

```js
namespace globalThis {
  type DbEvent<T> = Event & {
    target: {
      result: IDBCursor & { value: T }
    }
  }

  interface IDBRequest<T = any> extends EventTarget {
    addEventListener<D>(
      type: 'success',
      listener: (this: IDBRequest<T>, ev: DbEvent<D>) => any,
      options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions
    ): void
  }
}
```

then you can call it like so:

```js
store.openCursor().addEventListener<MyDataType>('success', ({ target }) => {
  const cursor = target.result
  const doc = target.result.value // MyDataType
  cursor.continue()
})
```